# Spring Integration Executor Channel using annotations code sample

Tags: spring, spring-integration, executor

My system diagram is attached.

[System Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEZYn.png)

**HOW THE FLOW WORKS:**

The spring integration flow reads input from a json file on C:\ and performs 2 actions:

1. Store into DB
2. Notify/print to user

**IMPORTANT CRITERIA:**

I want the store into DB flow to be independent of business logic (print to/notify user) i.e. a DB `exception/DB` success should not affect notify user.

Similarly notify user should not affect db flow.

I browsed and found out that I must use an executor channel to delegate the 'store into DB' to another thread.

I am unable to find a code sample for the execution channel. ***I need ONLY ANNOTATION based code as all other classes are annotation based***.

***WHAT I NEED: Code sample of ExecutorChannel - annotation based.***

Code inside 2 (reads json from file and send it to DB, custom busines logic)

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow readFromJSONFile() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("/path/to/File")
            .transform("Transformer to convert to Bean")
            .wireTap(
                    flow -> flow.handle(msg -> logger
                            .info("Message sent to common channel: " + msg.getPayload())))
                            .channel("Common Channel Name")
                            .get();
    }
```

Code inside 4:

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sendToDb() {

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("Common Channel Name")
            .handle("DAO Impl to store into DB") // I THINK THE MESSAGE SHOULD BE SENT TO AN EXECUTOR CHANNEL TO PROCESS ON A SEPARATE THREAD
            .get();
    }
```

Code inside 5:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sendToBusinessLogictoNotifyUser() {

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("Common Channel Name")
            .handle("Business Logic Class name")
                            .get();
    }
```

**Current behaviour:** If there is a DB exception, notify user fails as well. Instead I want it to get logged quietly.

> **NOTE:** I need annotaions only example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need an `ExecutorChannel` - simply set `ignoreFailures` to `true` on the pub/sub channel...

```
/**
 * Specify whether failures for one or more of the handlers should be
 * ignored. By default this is <code>false</code> meaning that an Exception
 * will be thrown whenever a handler fails. To override this and suppress
 * Exceptions, set the value to <code>true</code>.
 * @param ignoreFailures true if failures should be ignored.
 */
public void setIgnoreFailures(boolean ignoreFailures) {
```

If you want to log or otherwise handle exceptions on the DB store, you can add an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequesthandlerAdvice` to the component that does the DB store.

If you really want an `ExecutorChannel`, the [DSL section of the reference manual has an example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-channels).

```
.channel(MessageChannels.executor("executorChannel", this.taskExecutor))
```

Comment: Thankyou Gary. I will try it out. Quick question though, as per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/src/reference/asciidoc/handler-advice.adoc , abject is created using ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice(); Can I use @Autowired instead as I do not want to create an object inside the class.

Comment: I don't understand the question the advice is a bean: `@Bean public Advice expressionAdvice()` so, of course it can be autowired.