# Spring Integration + SpringBoot JUnit tries to connect to DB unexpectedly

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-integration

Please refer to system diagram attached.

[system diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIjn5.png)

***ISSUE:   When I try to post message to input channel, the code tries to connect to the DB and throws an exception that it is unable to connect.***

Code inside 5 -> Read from a channel, apply Business Logic (empty for now) and send the response to another channel.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sendToBusinessLogictoNotifyExternalSystem() {

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("CommonChannelName")
            .handle("Business Logic Class name") // Business Logic empty for now
            .channel("QueuetoAnotherSystem")
                            .get();
    }
```

---

I have written the JUnit for 5 as given below,

```
@Autowired
    PublishSubscribeChannel CommonChannelName;
    @Autowired
    MessageChannel QueuetoAnotherSystem;

    @Test
    public void sendToBusinessLogictoNotifyExternalSystem() {
        Message<?> message = (Message<?>) MessageBuilder.withPayload("World")
                .setHeader(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL, QueuetoAnotherSystem).build();
        this.CommonChannelName.send((org.springframework.messaging.Message<?>) message);
        Message<?> receive = QueuetoAnotherSystem.receive(5000);

        assertNotNull(receive);
        assertEquals("World", receive.getPayload());
    }
```

ISSUE: As you can see from the system diagram, my code also has a DB connection on a different flow.

When I try to post message to producer channel, the code tries to connect to the DB and throws an exception that it is unable to connect.

I do not want this to happen, because the JUnit should never be related to the DB, and should run anywhere, anytime.

```
How do I fix this exception?
```

**NOTE:** Not sure if it matters, the application is a Spring Boot application. I have used Spring Integration inside the code to read and write from/to queues.

Comment: @GaryRussell - Will you be able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the common channel is a publish/subscribe channel, the message goes to both flows.

If this is a follow-up to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535484/spring-integration-executor-channel-using-annotations-code-sample/50537931#50537931), you can prevent the DB flow from being invoked by calling `stop()` on the `sendToDb` flow (as long as you set `ignoreFailures` to true on the pub/sub channel, like I suggested there.

```
((Lifecycle) sendToDb).stop();
```

Comment: Thankyou @Gary. I cannot seem to make it work. I get no errors, but the method to be tested is not invoked either. I have included the code below as a separate answer to preserve formatting. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

**JUNIT TEST CASE - UPDATED:**

```
@Autowired
    PublishSubscribeChannel CommonChannelName;
    @Autowired
    MessageChannel QueuetoAnotherSystem;
    @Autowired
    SendResponsetoDBConfig sendResponsetoDBConfig;

    @Test
    public void sendToBusinessLogictoNotifyExternalSystem() {
        Lifecycle flowToDB = ((Lifecycle) sendResponsetoDBConfig.sendToDb());
        flowToDB.stop();
        Message<?> message = (Message<?>) MessageBuilder.withPayload("World")
                .setHeader(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL, QueuetoAnotherSystem).build();
        this.CommonChannelName.send((org.springframework.messaging.Message<?>) message);
        Message<?> receive = QueuetoAnotherSystem.receive(5000);

        assertNotNull(receive);
        assertEquals("World", receive.getPayload());
    }
```

**CODE FOR 4:   The flow that handles message to DB**

```
    public class SendResponsetoDBConfig {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sendToDb() {
    System.out.println("******************* Inside SendResponsetoDBConfig.sendToDb ***********");
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("Common Channel Name")
            .handle("DAO Impl to store into DB")
            .get();
    }   
}
```

**NOTE:** ******************* Inside SendResponsetoDBConfig.sendToDb *********** never gets printed.