# Null Channel maximum size - Spring Integration Flow

Tags: null, spring-integration, channel

This is a follow up to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545304/spring-integration-springboot-junit-tries-to-connect-to-db-unexpectedly/50545837#50545837)

The system diagram is available above.

**MY QUESTION:**

By default, what is the size of `new NullChannel()` in Spring Integration?

What is the maximum no. of messages can it hold?

I have not written any code to consume from the null channel. Will messages be deleted on its own if it is not consumed?

***Code inside 2 is***:

```
public IntegrationFlow handleJmsInput() throws Exception {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms
                    .inboundGateway(jmsConnectionFactory())
                    .destination(
                            "PRODUCER QUEUE NAME")
                    .errorChannel(nullableChannel()))
            .transform("Class to convert JSON to Bean")
            .channel("Common channel name").get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel nullableChannel() {
    return new NullChannel();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "size"; `NullChannel` simply discards the message; it is similar to `/dev/nul` on Unix.

You cannot "consume" from `NullChannel` (you can, but you'll never get a message).

While it doesn't hurt anything, you don't need a bean; the framework configures one for you; use `.errorChannel("nullChannel")` or `.errorChannel(IntegrationContextUtils.NULL_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME)`.

Comment: Thankyou @Gary. Please mark the above answer as accepted. I do not have enough reputation points to accept answers.