# Spring Integration - no response on reply channel

Tags: junit, spring-integration

This is a follow up question to [Spring Integration Executor Channel using annotations code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535484/spring-integration-executor-channel-using-annotations-code-sample/50537931#50537931).

System diagram is attached [image].

I am trying to test the box highlighted in red by posting a message into 'Common channel' and reading from REPLY_CHANNEL set in the msg.

'Common channel' is a publish subscribe channel.
REPLY_CHANNEL is a QueueChannel.

Since this is a JUnit test, I have mocked jdbcTemplate, datasource and the Impl to ignore any DB calls.

My issue is:
***When I post a message onto 'Common Channel', I do not receive any message on the REPLY_CHANNEL. The junit keeps waiting for a response.***

What should I change to get a response on the REPLY_CHANNEL?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class) --------- 1 
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class QueuetoQueueTest {
    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration { ------------------------------------- 2
        @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
        public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateMock = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
            return jdbcTemplateMock;
        }

        @Bean(name = "dataSource")
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DataSource dataSourceMock = Mockito.mock(DataSource.class);
            return dataSourceMock;
        }

        @Bean(name = "entityManager")
        public EntityManager entityManager() {
            EntityManager entityManagerMock = Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class);
            return entityManagerMock;
        }

        @Bean(name = "ResponseChannel")
        public QueueChannel getReplyQueueChannel() {
            return new QueueChannel();
        }

//This channel serves as the 'common channel' in the diagram
        @Bean(name = "processRequestSubscribableChannel")
        public MessageChannel getPublishSubscribeChannel() {
            return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
        }
    }

    @Mock
    DBStoreDaoImpl dbStoreDaoImpl;

    @Test
    public void testDBConnectivity() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @InjectMocks -------------------------------------------------------------- 3
    StoretoDBConfig storetoDBConfig = new StoretoDBConfig();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ResponseChannel")
    QueueChannel ResponseChannel;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("processRequestSubscribableChannel")
    MessageChannel processRequestSubscribableChannel;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void outboundtoQueueTest() {
        try {
            when(dbStoreDaoImpl.storeToDB(any()))
                    .thenReturn(1); ----------------------------------------------- 4

            //create message
            Message message = (Message<String>) MessageBuilder
                    .withPayload("Hello")
                    .setHeader(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL, ResponseChannel)
                    .build();

            //send message
            processRequestSubscribableChannel.send(message);
            System.out
                    .println("Listening on InstructionResponseHandlertoEventProcessorQueue");

            //wait for response on reply channel
            Message<?> response = ResponseChannel.receive(); ----------------------- 5
            System.out.println("***************RECEIVED: "
                    + response.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

1. Load 'ContextConfiguration' for JUnit so that DB is not accessed.
2. This is how you load custom configuration in JUnit as per https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles

Inside the config class, we mock jdbcTemplate, dataSource, entityManager and define the 'common channel' on which the request is posted and ResponseChannel.

3. Inject jdbcTemplate, dataSource mock into StoretoDBConfig so that the DB is not hit
4. Mock DaoImpl class so that DB calls are ignored
5. *The test blocks here because there is no response on the REPLY_CHANNEL*

UPDATED CODE:

```
Code inside 5 (the class that reads from common channel):

    @Configuration
    class HandleRequestConfig {

        //Common channel - refer diagram
        @Autowired
        PublishSubscribeChannel processRequestSubscribableChannel;

        //Step 9 - This channel is used to send queue to the downstream system
        @Autowired
        PublishSubscribeChannel forwardToExternalSystemQueue;

        public void handle() {
            IntegrationFlows.from("processRequestSubscribableChannel")          // Read from 'Common channel'
            .wireTap(flow->flow.handle(msg -> System.out.println("Msg received on processRequestSubscribableChannel"+ msg.getPayload())))
            .handle(RequestProcessor,"validateMessage")                         // Perform custom business logic - no logic for now, return the msg as is   
            .wireTap(flow->flow.handle(msg -> System.out.println("Msg received on RequestProcessor"+ msg.getPayload())))
            .channel("forwardToExternalSystemQueue");                           // Post to 'Channel to another system' 
            }

    }

    //Code inside step 8 - 'Custom Business Logic' 
    @Configuration
    class RequestProcessor {
        public Message<?> validateMessage(Message<?> msg) {
            return msg;
        }
    }
```

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE:**
I have individual junit test cases for the business logic. I am trying to test that when the request is posted into the 'common channel', the response is received on 'channel to another system'.

**Why I cannot use the original ApplicationContext:** Because it connects to the DB, and I do not want my JUnit to connect to the DB or use an embedded database. I want any calls to the DB to be ignored.

I have set the reply channel to 'ResponseChannel', shouldn't the 'Custom Business Logic' send its response to 'ResponseChannel'?

If I have to listen on a different channel for the response, I am willing to do so. All I want to test is whether the message I am sending on 'common channel' is received on 'channel to other system'.

UPDATE 2:
Addressing Artem's questions.
Thankyou Artem for your suggestions.

***Is 'HandlerRequestConfig' included in the test configuration?*** - We cannot directly call the handle() method. Instead I thought if I post on 'processRequestSubscribableChannel', the handle() method inside HandleRequestConfig will be invoked since it listens on the same channel. Is this wrong? How do I test HandleRequestConfig.handle() method then?

I added wiretap to the end of each step in HandleRequestConfig (code updated). I find that none of the wiretap message is printed. This means that the msg I am posting is not even reaching the input channel 'processRequestSubscribableChannel'. What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I tried removing the 'processRequestSubscribableChannel' bean inside Configuration (so that the actual 'processRequestSubscribableChannel' in the applicationContext is used). I am getting an unsatisfied dependency error - Expected atleast 1 bean with configuration PublishSubscribeChannel.

Update 3: Posted details Artem requested.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class QueuetoQueueTest  {

//  Step 1 - Mocking jdbcTemplate, dataSource, entityManager so that it doesn't connect to the DB
        @MockBean
        @Qualifier("jdbcTemplate")
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        @MockBean
        @Qualifier("dataSource")
        public DataSource dataSource;

        @MockBean
        @Qualifier("entityManager")
        public EntityManager entityManager;

        @Bean(name = "ResponseChannel")
        public PublishSubscribeChannel getReplyQueueChannel() {
            return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
        }

        //Mocking the DB class
        @MockBean
        @Qualifier("dbStoreDaoImpl")
        DBStoreDaoImpl  dbStoreDaoImpl ;


        //Inject the mock objects created above into the flow that stores data into the DB.
        @InjectMocks
        StoretoDBConfig storetoDBConfig = new StoretoDBConfig();

//Step 2 - Injecting MessageChannel used in the actual ApplicationContext
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("processRequestSubscribableChannel")
        MessageChannel processRequestSubscribableChannel;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void outboundtoQueueTest() {
        try {
            when(dbStoreDaoImpl.storeToDB(any()))
                    .thenReturn(1);

            //create message
            Message message = (Message<?>) MessageBuilder
                    .withPayload("Hello")
                    .build();
            //send message - this channel is the actual channel used in ApplicationContext
            processRequestSubscribableChannel.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### ERROR I AM GETTING: The code tries to connect to the DB and throws an error.

**UPDATE 1: Code inside StoretoDBConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class StoretoDBConfig {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

/*
 * Below code is irrelevant to our current problem - Including for reference.
 * 
 * storing into DB is delegated to a separate thread.
 *
 *  @Bean
 *  public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
 *      return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
 *  }
 *  
 *  @Bean(name="executorChannelToDB")
 *  public ExecutorChannel outboundRequests() {
 *      return new ExecutorChannel(taskExecutor());
 *  }
 *  @Bean(name = "DBFailureChannel")
 *  public static MessageChannel getFailureChannel() {
 *      return new DirectChannel();
 *  }
 *  private static final Logger logger = Logger
 *              .getLogger(InstructionResponseHandlerOutboundtoDBConfig.class);
*/
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow handle() {
    /*
     * Read from 'common channel' - processRequestSubscribableChannel and send to separate thread that stores into DB.
     *
     /
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("processRequestSubscribableChannel")
                .channel("executorChannelToDB").get();
    }
}
```

CODE THAT STORES INTO DB ON THE SEPARATE THREAD:

```
@Repository
public class DBStoreDaoImpl implements DBStoreDao {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "executorChannelToDB")
    public void storetoDB(Message<?> msg) throws Exception {
            String insertQuery ="Insert into DBTable(MESSAGE) VALUES(?)";
            jdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery, msg.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: @GaryRussell, will you be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Please, show us what is subscribed to that `Common channel`. Your diagram somehow is not related to what you show us. The code you demonstrate is not full.

The real problem with the `replyChannel` that something really has to send a message to it. If your flow is just *one-way* - send, store and nothing to return, - then you indeed won't get anything for this one. That's why would to show those channel adapters.

The best way to observe the message journey is to turn on debug logging for the `org.springframework.integration` category.

Although I see that you declare those channels as is in the `ContextConfiguration` and there is really no any subscribers to the `getRequestChannel`. Therefore nobody is going to consume your message and, of course, nobody is going to send you a reply.

Please, reconsider your test class to use the real application context. Otherwise it is fully unclear what you would like to achieve if you really don't test your flow...

Comment: thankyou for responding. added information you need.

Comment: Is that `HandleRequestConfig` included to the test configuration? Can you be sure that your `RequestProcessor` is called? You can add a `ChannelInterceptor` to the `forwardToExternalSystemQueue` channel and verify its interaction in the test. Also pay attention to the testing Framework we suggest: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/testing.html#test-context

Comment: Thanks Artem for your suggestions.

Comment: I have entered my response as a separate answer as it is too long to fit into comments.

Comment: Your approach and thought is correct, only what I'm not sure in is the fact if that `HandleRequestConfig` is called really when you send a message to the `processRequestSubscribableChannel` from your test-case.

Comment: I believe that your problem is because you don't load your real flow into the test-case. It is fully unclear how that `HandleRequestConfig` is going to be involved in the test context if you provide there only your inner `ContextConfiguration` . Consider to study how `@SpringBootTest` works: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing

Comment: Edited question as you suggested. Just to clarify, If I have 2 ApplicationContext  - one for the actual flow, and one for test, and I create 2 separate PublishSubscribeChannel inside them; the two channels are actually different. So posting a message into channel for test does not send it to the channel used in the actual flow?

What I actually need to do now is to find a way to use the channel from the actual ApplicationContext in my test?

Comment: So, you don't need those new channels in the test context. You just need to use a real context configuration class, mock service as you do now, and inject the real message channels to your test class. This way you will send message to the real channel and will be able to see how message travels through your real and mocked components. And yes: before sending a test message you really can add a `WireTap` to your `forwardToExternalSystemQueue` to verify in the end of test that everything goes well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173077/discussion-between-user1478392-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: No, I don't chat here on SO. It's very bad from usability perspective

Comment: Ok. I need a bit of coding help. 

You just need to use a real context configuration class, mock service as you do now - Do I remove the inner static configuration class for this? and just mock jdbcTemplate, dataSource, entityManager and service class inside the JUnit?

Comment: Inject the real message channels to your test class - 
If I use 

Autowired
PublishSubscribeChannel processRequestSubscribableChannel; 
Autowired
PublishSubscribeChannel forwardToExternalSystemQueue; 

I get an error 'Unsatisfied Dependency - Expected atleast one bean with configuration PublisSubscribeChannel'.

Comment: Sorry, it's really a mess. Let's go simple steps. How about to configure your test class with your real context configuration and inject channels from there? For the mocking services you can consider to use a `@MockBean` from Spring Boot.

Comment: Posted the code as an answer. I will remove it as soon as you read it, and update the final answer in the question.

Comment: Thankyou Artem, I will send you a sample project shortly. Do you have an email address I can send the project to?

Comment: No, please, share the GitHub project here. We are developing OpenSource and everything we do should be visible in the public. That's why I asked you to make as simple project as possible, with as business-agnostic content as possible

Comment: Of course, I will create a project and share it. Thankyou for taking time to help me out.